# Remote connection to SQL Server DB from WPF application

Tags: .net, sql-server, remote-access, sql-server-2016

Do I need to install SQL Server (Client tools) to a computer on which I am going to put one WPF application, which accesses SQL Server DB remotely?

The PC will have fresh new Windows and I wonder is it enough for running the application just to install the appropriate .NET Framework and to configure the connection string (no installation of any SQL Server stuff).

P.S. (DB - SQL Server Express 2016.) Let's say I've configured the server's DB and Firewall to accept remote access.

Thanks.

-- Conclusion: No need of SQL Server Client tools in the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll only need appropriate .NET Framework.

I'm unable to find any sources to my statement but I have used a remote database server for development before so it should not be an issue when deploying an application.

I found this instruction for SQL Server Compact and there they package sql-binaries with the application. When contacting a remote sql-server your deployed program should have all it need.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174619(v=sql.110).aspx