# Do I need to install SQL Server at both side client and server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a forms based application which has a SQL Server database, this database file will be stored on the server machine.

I want to know if I need to install SQL Server at both side client and server machine.

What I have tried:

I am installing SQL Server at server side and configuring windows firewall and enabling the tcp/ip protocol.

Comment: You only need to install `SQL Server` on the Server machine

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel,or one more thing is what type of permission i need to give at client side for database file in extra.

Comment: basically client does not need to access the file at all on the SQL Server machine. You grant the table access to the client login ID

Comment: You need only a driver on the client, for Java this would be JDBC

Comment: Thank You @Squirrel Please Write your answer so i can accept your answer and thank you so much to be helpful.

Comment: i am using SQLClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this thread, it might be helpful for your question:
[Remote connection to SQL Server DB from WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700131/remote-connection-to-sql-server-db-from-wpf-application)

In short - no, you need it on the server only.